# XML jquery parsing: Show only results with certain value

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

for example I've got this XML:

```
<data>
    <area>
        <state>SABAH</state>
        <parlim>P1</parlim>
        <name>Alice Smith</name>
    </area>
    <area>
        <state>SABAH</state>
        <parlim>P2</parlim>
        <name>John Smith</name>
    </area>
    <area>
        <state>SABAH</state>
        <parlim>P3</parlim>
        <name>Peter Smith</name>
    </area>
    <area>
        <state>SARAWAK</state>
        <parlim>P4</parlim>
        <name>Paul Smith</name>
    </area>
</data>
```

I'm parsing it to a html table with jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "parse.xml", 
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
   $(xml).find('area').each(function(){
    var Col0 = $(this).find('state').text();
    var Col1 = $(this).find('parlim').text();
    var Col2 = $(this).find('name').text();
    $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Col0+'</td><td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td>').appendTo('#chart');
   });
  }
 });
});
```

How do I make it so that it ONLY shows results with the state SABAH (which is the first 3 results)? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$(xml).find('area').each(function(){
    var Col0 = $(this).find('state').text();
    var Col1 = $(this).find('parlim').text();
    var Col2 = $(this).find('name').text();
    $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Col0+'</td><td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td>').appendTo('#chart');
});
```

to

```
$(xml).find('area').each(function(){
    var Col0 = $(this).find('state').text();
    // check if Col0 = SABAH
    if (Col0 === 'SABAH') { 
       var Col1 = $(this).find('parlim').text();
       var Col2 = $(this).find('name').text();
       $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Col0+'</td><td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td>').appendTo('#chart');
    }
});
```

This uses an `if` statement to check the text in the `state` tag to decide whether to proceed

Comment: Thanks alot, it works. you are so fast I cant tick now :) will tick answer after. Thanks again